# Android programming - Notification drawer is turning white for some users

Tags: android, android-studio

As stated in my title, some users of my app are experiencing as what they call a "White bar" in their app. However I believe this is the notification drawer turning white. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Picture:
[image]

Comment: lower your targetSdk to 19 may work

Answer (score -1):

Actually its action bar, you can hide it in this way:In res->styles.xml add the following tag into the style tag to hide it:

```
 <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
```